# How to simplify/make code better containing repetitive case and with statements?

Tags: excel, vba

I have pieced together a code to create an automated heat map. Unless I find some shortcut the code will end up being several thousand lines long. If anyone has the patience to explain the steps on how to simplify this in novice level terms that would be amazing. An example would be ideal, I work well with those.

I've been told to make a separate routine for each Case with just the code for that case and then pass the Range to be affected as a parameter to each "sub". I don't know what that looks like, so it did not go well when I tried it on my own. The code below is just an example of one case for the cell B13. My whole code has cases from 1.0-5.0 in .1 increments and this will repeat for cells B15, B17, B19, B21, B23, C13, C13... (with corresponding cells on Sheet2) so it becomes extremely long very quickly which is why I have the Worksheet_Change function at the top because including my code all in one caused the "Procedure too Long" error.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    B13   
End Sub

Sub B13(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B13")) Is Nothing Then

        Select Case Range("B13").Value

        Case 2

                With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B11").Interior
                    .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
                    .Gradient.Degree = 180
                    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
                End With

                With 

                     Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B11").Interior
                    .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
                    .Color = RGB(253, 200, 25)
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With

                With 
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B11").Interior
                    .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.04)
                    .Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With

                With 
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B11").Interior
                    .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.09)
                    .Color = RGB(143, 207, 80)
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With

                With 
                     Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B11").Interior
                    .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.15)
                    .Color = RGB(143, 207, 80)
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With

                With
                     Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B11").Interior
                    .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
                    .Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                   End With

End Select
End If
End Sub
```

I'm hoping a simplified code will allow me to write out the different gradients for each Case just once and then somehow assign the cells automatically using a range.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is kind of unclear. You are trying to color cells based on values of `B13`? And every 0.1 increments need to be reflected in the color? An example input and expected output would help a lot.

Comment: Adding to @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, it is unclear what changes from cell `b13` to `c13` or any other cell. Are the increments the same, does the increment change if the cell value is not 2? A little more information seems necessary to help out.

Comment: This seems to be basically the same question as yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144227/byval-target-as-value-argument-not-optional-compile-error)... Did you get that to work? IF not, why didn't you follow up there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ByVal Target as Value Argument Not Optional Compile Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144227/byval-target-as-value-argument-not-optional-compile-error)

Comment: Create a separate sub for each type of gradient (assuming there are a fixed reasonable number of those), with a single parameter `rng As Range` - then in each of those subs work with `rng` instead of the hard-coded reference you have now.  Call the appropriate one of these and pass in the cell to be configured.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Sheet1 I was told to include the bare minimum code so what I have above is only for one case (when Sheet1B11=2 which shade Sheet1B11 with the above gradient. The full extent of my code has cases from 1.0-5.0 in .1 increments for every cell pair (Sheet1B13 and Sheet2B12, Sheet1B15 and Sheet2B13, etc). and the corresponding gradients for each value. The only way I've figured out how to make this work for more cells is by copying everything over for each cell pair leading to thousands of lines of code. Let me know if that makes sense. I can post more code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the type of thing which you can aim for - reduce the amount of repeated code in a layered way - you have one sub per type of gradient, and a single generic sub which applies each of those to a single cell.

```
Sub Tester()

    GradientOne Range("a1")
    GradientTwo Range("a2")

End Sub


Sub GradientOne(rng As Range)
    ApplyGradient rng, Array(0, 0.04, 0.09, 0.15, 1), _
                 Array(RGB(253, 200, 25), RGB(255, 192, 0), _
                       RGB(143, 207, 80), RGB(143, 207, 80), RGB(0, 176, 80))
End Sub

Sub GradientTwo(rng As Range)
    ApplyGradient rng, Array(0, 0.5, 1), _
                 Array(RGB(253, 200, 25), RGB(255, 192, 0), RGB(143, 207, 80))
End Sub

'apply gradient to rng, using stops in arrStops and colors in arrColors
Sub ApplyGradient(rng As Range, arrStops, arrColors)
    Dim i As Long
    With rng.Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
        .Gradient.Degree = 180
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
        For i = LBound(arrStops) To UBound(arrStops)
            With .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(arrStops(i))
                .Color = arrColors(i)
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How does this make the gradients change when the value in the reference cell changes? Maybe I should post my project or something so it makes more sense.

Comment: It's not a full solution, but an approach to allow you to reduce the total volume of your code.  It's not really clear exactly what you're doing, but it's clear there are more lines of code than are required...

Comment: What is the relationship between cell values and the applied shading?  Is it totally custom, or does it follow a rule?  You only show a single value (2) so it's not possible to tell...